# Mean value theorem for integrals proof task

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have to prove this task, but I have a problem. I'm sure I have to do this using the mean value theorem for integrals, but the problem is that it requires the function to be **continuous**, but it's not stated in the task that this function in fact is continuous. So I think we have to do it using contradiction method.
Could you help please and say if I'm right so far.

> 5. (HW) Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx > 1$, then there exists a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(c) > \frac{1}{b-a}$.

Comment: One of the conditions of integrability is being continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: but continuity is not a necessary condition for integrability

Comment: @insipidintegrator: this exercise is from a basic course of integration, so reference to measure theory has nothing to do here. Moreover, continuity a.e. is not enough to use means value theorem... Finally, continuity a.e. is not a condition for (Riemann) integrability and conversely, if a function is Riemann integrable, it's wrong that it's a.e. continuous. However, what is true is that $f$ is Riemann integrable iff the set of discontinuity of $f$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Hi @Surb, i'm new to measure theory and I remain a bit confused about your comment. Is "$f$ is continuous a.e." not the same statement as "the set of discontinuity of $f$ has measure zero"?

Comment: @Seansong: $f$ is continuous a.e. means that there is a continuous function $g$ s.t. $f=g$ a.e. For exemple, $f(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)$ is nowhere continuous, but is continuous a.e. however, $f(x)=\boldsymbol 1_{(0,\infty )}(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ only, but it's not continuous a.e.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the standard Lebesgue measure.

You can prove even more, namely that the set
$$
A=\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)>1/(b-a)\}
$$
has positive measure. Suppose it doesn't and consider the function defined over $[a,b]$ by
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) & x\notin A \\[6px] 0 & x\in A \end{cases}
$$
where, instead of $0$ you can use any value so long as it's $\le1/(b-a)$.

Then we have
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b g(x)\,dx
$$
because the functions coincide almost everywhere.

Moreover, $g(x)\le 1/(b-a)$ for every $x\in[a,b]$, and by monotonicity of the integral we get
$$
\int_a^b g(x)\,dx\le \int_a^b\frac{1}{b-a}\,dx=1
$$
which contradicts the assumption on $f$.

In other words, you have plenty of points $c$ where $f(c)>1/(b-a)$ to choose from.

Comment: hello, why can we write that int_a_b g(x)dx = int_a_b f(x)dx. and why is g(x) <= 1/(b-a). Sorry, I'm quite new to this @egreg

Comment: @Allegrina Two functions that differ only on a set of measure zero have the same integral. We have $g(x)\le 1/(b-a)$ by construction: if $f(x)\le 1/(b-a)$, that is, $x\notin A$, we define $g(x)=f(x)$; otherwise $g(x)=0<1/(b-a)$.

Comment: thank you, I got it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $$\int_a^b f>1.$$
Then, $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f>\frac{1}{b-a}.\tag{1}$$
If $f(x)\leq \frac{1}{b-a}$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, then $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f\leq \frac{1}{b-a},$$
which contradict $(1)$. Therefore, $f(c)>\frac{1}{b-a}$ for some $c\in (a,b)$.